# Scrapy 1.8.0 returns error 500, but Python code returns success 200

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, header, twisted

The address is: 'https://planningapi.agileapplications.co.uk/api/application/search?reference=GDO+19%2F12'

I can easily download this page by Python requests library:

```
headers = {
            'x-client': 'EXMOOR',
            'x-product': 'CITIZENPORTAL',
            'x-service': 'PA',
            }
url='https://planningapi.agileapplications.co.uk/api/application/search?reference=GDO+19%2F12'
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

or I can easily download the page via CURL:

```
curl 'https://planningapi.agileapplications.co.uk/api/application/search?reference=GDO+19%2F12' -H 'x-product: CITIZENPORTAL' -H 'x-service: PA' -H 'x-client: EXMOOR'
```

They both return status 200 result:

```
{"total":1,"results":[{"id":18468,"reference":"GDO 19/12","proposal":"Prior notification for excavations to bury tanks and trenches to lay water pipes","location":"Land North West of North and South Ley, Exford, Minehead, Somerset.","username":"","applicantSurname":"Mr & Mrs M Burnett","agentName":"JCH Planning Limited","decisionText":null,"registrationDate":"2019-10-04","decisionDate":"2019-10-30","finalGrantDate":null,"appealLodgedDate":null,"appealDecisionDate":null,"areaId":[],"wardId":[],"parishId":[3],"responded":null,"lastLetterDate":null,"targetResponseDate":null}]}
```

But the Scrapy returns status 500 error:

```
formdata = {'reference': 'GDO 19/12', }

headers = {
    'x-client': 'EXMOOR',
    'x-product': 'CITIZENPORTAL',
    'x-service': 'PA',
    }

fr = scrapy.FormRequest(
    url='https://planningapi.agileapplications.co.uk/api/application/search',
    method='GET',
    meta=response.meta,
    headers=headers,
    formdata=formdata,
    dont_filter=True,
    callback=self.ref_result_2,
    )

yield fr
```

Maybe it is because Scrapy capitalizes headers keys (I've tried un-capitalizing them, but then Twisted does the same - it capitalizes them again), maybe for some other reason.

How can I adjust my Scrapy 1.8.0 code to successfully get the same result as Python requests do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really caused by the fact that Scrapy capitalizes the header fields. If you try to capitalize then in the cURL command, you'll get the same error as you get with Scrapy (you can test it in Scrapy setting `handle_httpstatus_list` in the spider class and printing the `response.text` in the parse method). As you also already stated, Twisted does the same so overriding `scrapy.http.Headers` is not the solution.

However, you can do a trick to make Twisted not capitalize specific headers, as per [this issue comment](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2711#issuecomment-367342284):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pprint import pprint
import scrapy
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers as TwistedHeaders

TwistedHeaders._caseMappings.update({
    b'x-client': b'x-client',
    b'x-product': b'x-product',
    b'x-service': b'x-service',
})

class Foo(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'foo'
    handle_httpstatus_list = [500]

    def start_requests(self):
        formdata = {'reference': 'GDO 19/12'}
        headers = {
            'x-client': 'EXMOOR',
            'x-product': 'CITIZENPORTAL',
            'x-service': 'PA'
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            'https://planningapi.agileapplications.co.uk/api/application/search',
            method='GET', headers=headers, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        pprint(response.text)
```

Now you'll get the results. On the other hand, as per [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), section 3.2., the header fields should be case-insensitive.